# Best way to have a cover sized responsive video background on a website

Tags: html, css, youtube, html5-video

I have tried to have to go with the `mp4` approach with HTML5 `<video>` tags. Seems to work great, fully responsive, and takes the whole available space, without showing any weird black padding as YouTube player does. Except that I cannot make it always centered (cover size background). And I cannot find a way to upload a video and get a direct `mp4` link. I tried uploading to Dropbox and Streamable. Both come with their own annoying landing page which does not work with `<video>`.

I gave up on that `<video>` idea and decided to go with a Youtube player. Which does not work at all. Here is what I have,

```html
<section class="hero">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" class="hero-video" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay; encrypted-media;"
        src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/1CL_X5O71gk?vq=hd1080&autoplay=1&loop=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&fs=0&controls=0&disablekb=1&controls=0&mute=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&html5=1">
    </iframe>
    <img class="logo" src="./assets/logo.png" alt="logo" title="logo" />
</section>
```

and the CSS used,

```css
.hero-video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.hero {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(94,88,88,0.5), rgba(94,88,88,0.5));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

To play around with the ideas,

https://jsfiddle.net/temurih/xpkoe08j/7/

---

**Second Approach:**

In `<video>` tag approach, I was not able to center (cover size) the video. It looks weird on cellular devices.

```html
<section class="hero">
    <video autoplay muted loop class="hero-video">
        <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/490883126.hd.mp4?s=ce7a3266505de5d5f8f51cd9c134e21d7b1d21bf&profile_id=175" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    <img class="logo" src="./assets/logo.png" alt="logo" title="logo" />
</section>
```

CSS is more or less the same,

```css
.hero-video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.hero {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(94,88,88,0.5), rgba(94,88,88,0.5));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

To play around with the ideas,

https://jsfiddle.net/temurih/xpkoe08j/12/

Comment: You don't have any real control inside the YouTube player.  If you go back to your video tag, you just need `object-fit: cover` in your CSS.

Comment: but then how would I upload a video somewhere and get a `mp4` link?

Comment: The same way you do any of the other files associated with your website.

Comment: @Brad not really... The video I am trying to upload is like `215MB`. And the general hosting providers don't allow you to upload anything more than `100MB` file. I tried to talk my client out of it, but they want exactly that video. And I cannot seem to find a place to upload a `mp4` video and get a direct link. You can upload on Youtube, but it does not work well with responsiveness and the cover sizing.

Comment: How long is the video?  Chances are, it's encoded at too high of a bitrate anyway.  (Your users aren't going to want to download a 215MB background video.)  You can transcode it to a lower bitrate with FFmpeg.  Frankly, I can't think of a single hosting provider that limits you to 100MB resources.  You could put it up on AWS S3 or Digital Ocean Spaces if you want.

Comment: The video is a minute long and really high resolution. Github for one stops you at `100MB` file size unless you pay extra.

Comment: Why is a background video of such a high resolution?  At a minimum, you're going to need to offer this up with multiple bitrates via HLS, because a whole ton of people are not going to be able to stream that file fast enough to play.

Comment: @Brad Idk man! I have told them that. But that is what they want.

Comment: It's up to you to interpret requirements and implement the best tradeoffs.  I highly doubt your customer wants a web page where a background video only works for 20% of the people who see it, and is broken for the rest.  I bet they want a video on the background as high quality as possible for the connection available.

Comment: @Brad I was able to upload it to Vimeo and get a `mp4` link. Where do you want me to add `object-fit` property? I tried everywhere! https://jsfiddle.net/temurih/xpkoe08j/11/

Comment: The video is pinned to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code, just set the CSS to set the video size to be the size of its parent.  Then, set `object-fit` to `cover`:

```
.hero-video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, did not realize that I had `min-width` and `min-height`, which I added to experiment with different things. Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!